# flutter apk test on my friends' android devices

Tags: android, flutter, apk

I've finally completed building my own first flutter app, a lot thanks to SO. But I've still got an issue about testing my flutter apk in others' devices. So, finally i got 'app-release.apk', 'app.apk' and few more apk-related files. So excited, I sent those files to my friends, but friends told me that the app is well downloaded but not able to open it. So here's the question! Is there any additional essential commands to successfully open the apk file on real android device? If so, is there really no way to install and successfully open and use .apk or .aab flutter app in my friends' android device? I want to test my app in friends' device BEFORE google's review is done! Thank you in advance [:

Comment: Are you using the apks that were generated for the emulator?

Comment: Thanks for comment [: I used default flutter command from android studio tool bar 'build - flutter(first one) - build apk(among four options)'!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hey congratulations that you have completed the first app.

you have to run this command

`flutter build apk --split-per-abi`

this command gives your three apk file so you have to ask your friend that which processor he has. Depends on it you will give it.

```
<app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
<app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-arm64-v8a-release.apk
<app dir>/build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-x86_64-release.apk
```

Make sure your app is running perfectly in release mode as well
you can verify it via `flutter run --release -v`.

`-v` means verbose you can see the complete logs of your flutter app

Answer (score 0):

I use VSCode so can't comment on AS. Basically though, to give your friends apks that they can side load on Android devices. In the terminal, first do a Flutter clean and when it completes execute 'flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm64'. The resultant app.apk in your outputs folder should be able to run on their devices.